# Node.js dtrace error in Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, profiling, dtrace

I try DTrace the Node.js application on the Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'profile-97/execname == "node" && arg1/{ @[jstack(150, 8000)] = count(); } tick-60s { exit(0); }' &> /tmp/dtrace.out
```

And this is what I have: http://pastebin.com/NjbR2zug

There are an errors like this:

```
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 28: profile:::profile-97): invalid address (0x5) in action #2
```

Node.js installed both by a Brew and a NVM, I tried launch my app.js by both this installations.

What can I try to resolve this promlem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jstack()` action appears to be completely broken;  log a bug with Apple.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the solution?