# DTrace error in macOS Sierra

Tags: node.js, macos, macos-sierra, dtrace

I was trying to use a `dtrace` command in my macOS Sierra to profile a node.js application like this:

`sudo dtrace -x ustackframes=100 -n 'profile-97 /pid == 35526/ { @[ustack()] = count(); } tick-60s { exit(0); }' -o out.user_stacks`

and that's erroring out like this:

```
dtrace: description 'profile-97 ' matched 2 probes
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 37: profile:::profile-97): invalid address (0x405060700010203) in action #2
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 37: profile:::profile-97): invalid address (0x405060700010203) in action #2
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 37: profile:::profile-97): invalid address (0x6eac0bf) in action #2
```

I have googled and found this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275175/error-on-enabled-probe-syscallopen-nocancelentry-invalid-user-access-in-ac

but read that doing that is not safe. Can someone please explain what that error means and why it's caused? If I see errors like this, will dtrace produce correct `stack traces`?

How can I resolve this errors? Thanks

Comment: It might not be related to SIP. Look here: http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2012/11/14/dtracing-in-anger/ (they got the same error, apparently a known issue with DTrace on macOS). Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011482/node-js-dtrace-error-in-mac-os-x-yosemite

Comment: @robertklep I had a look at those pages but that didn't help

Comment: it's suggested that `ustack` (which is similar to `jstack` from what I understand) is broken on macOS, so you can't use it (as you already found out). You probably have to use another mechanism of profiling your app, for instance using `--prof` (documented here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/)